# css:hover color bug

Tags: html, css, colors, hover

I just noticed something weird, when creating a menu for a website. [Take a look at this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emcJQ/1/) which illustrates the problem.

Notice the small orange spot, to the right of the last letter when you hover on the menu-item.
**Why is this occurring?**

I can tone down the "orange effect" by lowering the contrast between the foreground and background color, but it does not solve the actual problem. Is this a bug, or is there a clever way to fix this?

I'm using Chrome on a Mac btw. I've noticed it doesn't occur in Firefox, so it's a browser-related issue.

**Update**
Thanks for the answers and suggestions on how to fix it! I accepted Marcel's answer as this seemed to be the most correct answer as to why it is occurring. I don't know if this is the case, but it seems to be a Webkit problem. If you notice the bug in any non-webkit browser, please say so, and I'll update this.

Comment: It's 2 pixels high and color `#3a0000`, weird... Thought it was just my eyes at first. I'm on windows 7 and saw it in Chrome10 but not FF4.

Comment: Pretty sure it has something to do with font smoothing/anti-aliasing in the browser, or maybe certain font rendering expanding beyond its "box size" and not being totally contained in the anchor by a "half-pixel" :) Looks like it could be a bug to me (albeit a small one). How you discovered this is beyond me...

Comment: It's very noticeable, when there is a large contrast between the colors. In the Fiddle, I've used black as hover color to illustrate the problem, but it's easy to notice with any other colors as well.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to just be an invalidation bug in WebKit.  File it on them?

Comment: Just did. Posted it on the Chromium site. Hopefully they'll take care of it from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) artifact. [Adding `opacity:.9999;`](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/M3M6R/) to the CSS rules for `li a` seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you add `padding-right: 1px;` to the li a, the orange dot will go away and let you keep the font.

As far as why it's occurring, the only thing I could think of was that the couple edge pixels of the T were extending past the edge of the anchor's box. Adding the padding expanded the box a little, but it seems rather hackish.

If you add a background colour to anchor, you can see the edge of the T is outside the background.